# Take stored email addresses from custom post type & turn into one string

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type, which has email and names stored.  I would like to take these email addresses and concatenate (join them) together into a single string. This string will be stored in a variable, and I will then assign this variable to  the `$email_to` in  wp_mail. Using a cron, the latest 3 posts will then be sent to the email addresses over a chosen frequency.

My Q: I am just looking for someone to point me in the right direction. Should I use a `foreach` to loop through all of these stored email addresses in the custom post type, and then concatenate them to the string stored in the variable?

**UPDATE**
I am not looking for someone to provide the code (that would be unreasonable). I am looking for a yes or no, & a little bit of guidance if possible.

Comment: Are you looking for a simple `join()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this. For my examples, I'm going to assume you've stored the emails in the `post_title` field.  [`wp_mail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) takes a string or array in the to field, so you can do something like this...

```
<?php
$emails = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'your_email_storing_type',
    'nopaging'  => true,
));

$to_send = array();

foreach ($emails as $e) {
    if (!e) {
        continue;
    }

    $to_send[] = $e->post_title;
}

wp_mail($to_send, /* ... */);
```

Or you can [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) them all together (which you shouldn't `wp_mail` will take care of it for you).

```
<?php
$emails = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'your_email_storing_type',
    'nopaging'  => true,
));

$to_send = array();

foreach ($emails as $e) {
    if (!e) {
        continue;
    }

    $to_send[] = $e->post_title;
}

wp_mail(implode(',', $to_send), /* ... */);
```

Or you could go directly to `wpdb` and offload the concatenation to MySQL.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$emails = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(post_title SEPARATOR ',') FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_title = 'your_email_storing_type'");

wp_mail($emails, /* ... */);
```